# How to change the picture we see on Facebook when we share a link of our website

Tags: facebook, share, facebook-opengraph

I've been looking for a while on Internet and coding, but i still cannot personalize the picture when i share article using Facebook share button.

I would like to put the picture of the shared article but instead the plugin show the picture of the author of the article.

Could someone help me with that please ?

Thank you a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use some metatags called OpenGraph, they should appear on the `<head>` of the html code

Example:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="place here the title you want to set on the FB share" />
<meta property="og:description" content="place here the description of the share" />
<meta property="og:url" content="place here the url of the page, in php you can use [Note 1]" />
<meta property="og:image" content="place here the url of the image you want to see on the FB share" />
```

The first one should have `website` string, don't touch it. The others should be modified by you.

**[Note 1]**
In php you can get it with:

```
(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
```

Comment: More info here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters

Comment: i've already try metatags but i doesn't i don't know what i'm missing :/

Comment: Try with this if you're placing the metas in the good way: http://opengraphcheck.com/